# Win32 Where is the console code running? Console hang when used from multiple threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, console

I have a Win32 app in C++ that uses two threads.
Thread A creates a console window using `AllocConsole()`.
Thread B prints into this console using `WriteFile` into the console handle (got from `GetStdHandle`).

For some reason, when both threads print simultaniously to the console my process hangs.

How can I fix this hang? What causes it?
I want to debug the message loop for the console (It's a window right? So it should have messages) but I don't know how to access it?

Comment: Got any code to go with that description?

Comment: Could you elaborate on '*... gets hang.*', please.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide any code, I'll just throw an educated guess in here:

As far as my knowledge goes, <strike>Win32 Console class is not thread safe (Unlike</strike> System.Console class in .NET which IS thread-safe).

This basically means that you should do some synchronization to prevent any errors; I have no idea if the hang in there is caused by such a problem or not though.

Please provide us with the code.

**EDIT:** 

 Please check  Raymond Chen's comment.

Comment: The console is thread safe, but it is synchronous. This means that if [one thread is reading from the console, another thread cannot write](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/02/10243553.aspx).

Comment: So multiple writes should go just fine?

Comment: Each write waits for the previous write to complete.

Comment: Synchronisation is needed if using the same device handle. If each thread uses its own (properly created) handle, synchronisation is done by the OS. Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you. In my case the handle must be shared since it's a sort of globaly instanced log library which is used sporadically between threads, so the "hang" was due to misuse of the synchronization object protecting the handle and the fact that the console is synchronous.
Just out of curiosity, is there any reference in MSDN for the fact that the console is synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in the *use of the same* device handle by the concurrent calls to `WriteFile()`.

Each thread needs it own device handle. Simply pulling it via `HANDLE = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` in the main thread an then using it in both threads to do the `WriteFile(HANDLE, ...)` most certainly won't work.

The straight forward way to get around this is to have each thread have its own value for `HANLDE` by a call to a `CreateFile()` using `CONOUT$`.

In the OP's case only thread B needs to create it's own handle by calling `CreateFile()`, thread A can use the value returned by `GetStdHandle()`, as it allocated the console.

For how to create a device handle for a console [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for "Console" in the "Remarks" Section.